# Pointing a bunch of subdomains to separate pages on a WP site

Tags: wordpress, multi-subdomains

So I need to deploy a landing page to 30-40 websites/domains. The landing pages are all pretty much the same bar some minor content tweaks and have been built in a wordpress theme. Each page would need to reside (seem to) in a subdomain of the destination site.

Got me to thinking that it would be far easier to manage if I can get each of the client sites to simply point their subdomain to version of a page on my server rather than having to deploy to 30-40 different sites.

Could anyone highlight any potential issues with this from a server perspective?
My server will be a Google Cloud Platform Bitnami Wordpress instance with adequate resources.

Cheers

Comment: Given what you are asking is about issues on the server, this may be the wrong place to be asking and it should be on the server fault site.

Comment: @Grif Are you planning on just having the client sites _forward_ visitors to their corresponding page on your server, or _point_ to them, which would imply using DNS (and isn't possible to do with URL paths). If they forward visitors to them, obviously the URL would change to a URL on your server. They also wouldn't have access to modify their content, check stats, etc...

Comment: @dan Hi, point (I think). The URL will be http://subdomain.domain.com but the page will be on our server, not theirs. We handle all modifications of the page anyway (hence why this might make sense) and we can provide them with relevant stats.

Comment: @Steve thanks for heads up. If I don't get answer here I'll give the Server Fault site a shot.

Comment: @Grif That's not really possible with DNS since you'd be pointing to a URL _path_, which DNS doesn't handle. They'll need to forward (redirect), or alternatively they could _iframe_ or _include_ the page from your server (using PHP for example) if they want the URL to remain theirs instead of yours.